# Error: Opportunity must have a primary quote in order to create an order.: [] - SBQQ CPQ Test class

Tags: unit-test, dml, failing-tests, cpq, order

I am very new to CPQ, and I am given a test class to write directly. When I try creating **order** in my test class, I am getting this error:  `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Opportunity must have a primary quote in order to create an order.: []` in **test class** - **testSetup**.

My test data factory:

```
    public with sharing class TestDataFactory {
    public TestDataFactory() {
    }
    
    public static Account getTestAccount(){
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Test Account';
        
        acc.Account_Cancel_Date__c = system.today();
        acc.Account_Category__c = 'Regional';
        return acc;
    }
    public static contact getTestContact(Account acc){
        contact cont = new contact();
        cont.lastname = 'Test Contact';
        //acc.LastName = 'Testtt';
        cont.Account = acc;
        return cont;
    }

    public static product2 getProduct(){
        product2 prods = new Product2(Name = 'Test Product 1', Line_of_Business__c = 'Dealer Inspire');
        return prods;
    }
    public static Pricing_Table__c getPricingTable(id prodId){
        Pricing_Table__c prt = new Pricing_Table__c(DI_Product__c = prodId, Billing_Type__c = 'Advance', DI_OEM__c = 'GM', Hinge_Day__c = 5, Legacy_PricebookEntryID__c = 'GMDigADUS', Dealer_Price__c = 123, DI_Brand_Name__c = 'Test', Docusign_Required__c = 'Yes', Wholesale__c = 321, InvoiceGroup__c = 'Acura_DigAd', Payment_Terms__c = '15', DIPricingMethod__c = 'Dealer Price');
        return prt;
    }

    public static SBQQ__Quote__c getTestQuote( id accId){
        SBQQ__Quote__c quo = new SBQQ__Quote__c();
        quo.SBQQ__Account__c = accId;
        quo.SBQQ__BillingCity__c = 'Hyderabad';
        quo.SBQQ__BillingCountry__c = 'India';
        quo.SBQQ__Key__c = '1233';
        quo.ApprovalStatus__c = 'Approved';
        quo.SBQQ__Ordered__c = false;
        quo.Legacy_Quote_Id__c = '0065b00000rFb18AAC';
        return quo;
    }
    public static Quote_Line_Migration__c getQuoteLineMigration(id quoteId){
        Quote_Line_Migration__c qli = new Quote_Line_Migration__c();
        qli.Quote__c = quoteId;
        qli.is_Processed__c = true;
        qli.Activated__c = true;
        qli.Legacy_Quote__c = '0065b00000rFb18AAC';
        qli.Legacy_Product__c = 'GMDigADUS';
        return qli;
    }
    public static Opportunity getOpportunity(id quoteId, id AccId){
        
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name = 'TestOpp1', StageName = 'Demo', Type = 'Existing Business', AccountId =AccId, LeadSource = 'DI Chat',
                                            CloseDate = Date.today(), Desired_Product_Services__c = 'Dealer Inspire',SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__c = quoteId);
        return o;
    }
    public static order getOrder(id quoteId, id oppId){
        Order ord = new Order();
        ord.Name = 'Test order';
        ord.status = 'Activated';
        ord.SBQQ__Quote__c = quoteId;
        ord.OpportunityId = oppId;
        //ord.QuoteId = quoteId;
        return ord;
    }

    public static Quote_Migration__c getQuoteMigration(){
        Quote_Migration__c qm = new Quote_Migration__c();
        qm.Legacy_Quote_Id__c = '0065b00000rFb18AAC';
        return qm;
    }
}
```

My testsetup in test class is:

```
 @testSetup
static void createRecords() {
    Account acc = TestDataFactory.getTestAccount();
    insert acc;
    Contact cont = TestDataFactory.getTestContact(acc);
    insert cont;
    SBQQ__Quote__c quo = TestDataFactory.getTestQuote(acc.Id);
    quo.SBQQ__Ordered__c = true;
    insert quo;
    system.debug(quo.Id);
    Quote_Line_Migration__c qlm = TestDataFactory.getQuoteLineMigration(quo.Id);
    qlm.contracted__c = false;
    insert qlm;
    opportunity opp = TestDataFactory.getOpportunity(quo.Id, acc.Id);
    insert opp;
    order ord = TestDataFactory.getOrder(quo.Id, opp.Id);
    insert ord; // Error: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Opportunity must have a primary quote in order to create an order.: []
}
```

During `insert ord`, I am getting the error `System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Opportunity must have a primary quote in order to create an order.: []`. Can I please get some help on how to rectify this error as I am new to CPQ

Answer (score 1):

The order can only be created against the primary quote (among potentially many quotes attached to the opportunity, eventually, one should be a primary).

In your test factory method : getTestQuote, add the following line,
**quo.SBQQ__Primary__c = true;**
and rerun please.

Answer (score 0):

An Order can be created and linked to an Opportunity. It can only be linked to a Quote when the Quote is Primary.

Set

```
ord.SBQQ__Quote__c = Null;
```

The test should run.